# Downcasting Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<MyTrait>> to Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<MyStruct>>

Tags: rust

The following code allows me to downcast from `Arc<MyTrait>` to `Arc<MyStruct>`:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
        fn as_any(self: Arc<Self>) -> Arc<dyn std::any::Any + Send + Sync>;
};

struct MyStruct {};

MyStruct impl MyTrait {
    fn as_any(self: std::sync::Arc<Self>) -> std::sync::Arc<dyn std::any::Any + Send + Sync> {
      self
    }
};
```

Now I am in the need to downcast from `Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<MyTrait>>` to `Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<MyStruct>` while keeping the original object alive as it is stored in the list to which other parts of the program have access to?

Adding
`fn as_any_rw(self: Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<Self>>) -> Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<dyn std::any::Any + Send + Sync>>;`
to the trait makes the compiler scream with

```
invalid `self` parameter type: std::sync::Arc<tokio::sync::RwLock<Self>>
type of `self` must be `Self` or a type that dereferences to it
consider changing to `self`, `&self`, `&mut self`, `self: Box<Self>`, `self: Rc<Self>`, `self: Arc<Self>`, or `self: Pin<P>` (where P is one of the previous types except `Self`)rustcE0307
```

I know that using enums is an alternative approach to solve my problem but I have to work with the existing structure.

Comment: You can't cast an `RwLock` into another `RwLock`. How should the original lock get notified if the other lock gets locked? What you *can* do is lock the lock, get a reference to the `MyTrait` object and then downcast the reference, if possible.

Comment: for _just_ fixing the error about `self` you can just use a different parameter name (e.g. `this`) and the trait will build, but I think you'll still have casting issues.

Comment: @Finomnis oh actually it would be enough for me to get a copy of the Arc<RwLock<T>> in that way the Arc would point to the same RwLock.

Comment: Yes of course, that's what `Arc` is for. But I thought you wanted to downcast it.

Comment: The duplicate applied to `RwLock` available [here on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5914a2891d2934ae48ea6c6dd3374fad).